# RavenDB facet takes to long query time

Tags: ravendb

I am new to ravendb and trying it out to see if it can do the job for the company i work for .

i updated a data of 10K records to the server .
each data looks like this :

```
{
  "ModelID": 371300,
  "Name": "6310I",
  "Image": "0/7/4/9/28599470c",
  "MinPrice": 200.0,
  "MaxPrice": 400.0,
  "StoreAmounts": 4,
  "AuctionAmounts": 0,
  "Popolarity": 16,
  "ViewScore": 0.0,
  "ReviewAmount": 4,
  "ReviewScore": 40,
  "Cat": "E-Cellphone",
  "CatID": 1100,
  "IsModel": true,
  "ParamsList": [
    {
      "ModelID": 371300,
      "Pid": 188396,
      "IntVal": 188402,
      "Param": "Nokia",
      "Name": "Manufacturer",
      "Unit": "",
      "UnitDir": "left",
      "PrOrder": 0,
      "IsModelPage": true
    },
    {
       "ModelID": 371305,
       "Pid": 398331,
       "IntVal": 1559552,
       "Param": "1.6",
       "Name": "Screen size",
       "Unit": "inch",
       "UnitDir": "left",
       "PrOrder": 1,
       "IsModelPage": false
},.....
```

where ParamsList is an array of all the attributes of a single product.

after building an index of :

```
from doc in docs.FastModels
from docParamsListItem in ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)doc.ParamsList).DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { Param = docParamsListItem.IntVal, Cat = doc.Cat }
```

and a facet of

```
 var facetSetupDoc = new FacetSetup
       {
           Id = "facets/Params2Facets",
           Facets = new List<Facet> { new Facet { Name = "Param" } }
       };
```

and search like this

```
  var facetResults = session.Query<FastModel>("ParamNewIndex")
               .Where(x => x.Cat == "e-cellphone")
               .ToFacets("facets/Params2Facets");
```

it takes more than a second to query and that is on only 10K of data . where our company has more than 1M products in DB.

am i doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to generate facets, you have to check for each & every individual value of `docParamsListItem.IntVal`. If you have a lot of them, that can take some time.
In general, you shouldn't have a lot of facets, since that make no sense, it doesn't help the user.
For integers, you usually use ranges, instead of the actual values.
For example, price within a certain range.
You use just the field for things like manufacturer, or the MegaPixels count, where you have lot number or items (about a dozen or two)

You didn't mention which build you are using, but we made some major improvements there recently.

Comment: Thanks Alot, lets say i would like to have all the manufacturers in the category amount of products per category : samsung (30),apple (5) .... , there are many of them (hundreds). is there a better way of doing that ?